# Utlizar rand en c para generar una secuencia de numeros aleatorios que vayan de 3 en 3?

Tags: c, random

¿Hay alguna forma simple en la que utilizando rand(sin usar otras funciones) pueda generar números aleatorios entre 45 y 75 (inclusive) y que estos sean `45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75`(es decir que vaya de 3 en 3)?

Se como realizar el intervalo pero no la secuencia.
El intervalo seria

> 45+(rand()%33)

Pero debería agregarle algo para realizar la secuencia.
Perdón si es muy básica la pregunta.

Comment: Primero que nada deberias mostrar que has intentando. Segundo, cual es la idea de usar rand, si ya sabes la secuencia que queres?

Comment: Donde entra lo _**aleatorio**_ en _"una secuencia de números que vayan de 3 en 3"_? Lo mejor sería crear el array/secuencia de 3 en 3 y luego _mezclarla_.

Comment: Se que se puede hacer asi,el problema es que ,el ejercicio  que estoy intentando realizar solo da un espacio minimo y no da lugar para meter for ni nada.

Comment: ¿Y cómo piensas asignar los valores retornados por `rand` a dicha secuencia? O ¿Sólo es mostrarlos via `stdout`?

Comment: Es solo mostrarlo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplemente genera números aleatorios entre `0` y `10`. El resultado lo multiplicas por `3` y le sumas `45`:

```
| Número | × 3 | + 45 |
+--------+-----+------+
|      0 |   0 |   45 |
|      1 |   3 |   48 |
|      2 |   6 |   51 |
|      3 |   9 |   54 |
|      4 |  12 |   57 |
|      5 |  15 |   60 |
|      6 |  18 |   63 |
|      7 |  21 |   66 |
|      8 |  24 |   69 |
|      9 |  27 |   72 |
|     10 |  30 |   75 |
```